# How to add/install binary library to Python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I downloaded a binary library from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) which I want to add to Python, but I don't know how to do it, please help.

Here's what I've tried:

```
try:
    import numpy
except:
    print "This implementation requires the numpy module."
    exit(0)
```

I downloaded the numpy .exe binary, but I don't know where to put it. I use Windows and Python 3.3

Comment: Did you download the right match between Python 32/64 bit and Numpy 32/64 bit? If you are using 32-bit Python, you need to download the 32-bit Numpy.

Comment: Yes I did but where to put the exe file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I now just downloaded the official release from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.7.0). It was a installer. Now it works.